# Understanding how PyAudio works

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

Can someone help me understand how to use pyaudio? What is chunk? What is the use of frames list? what is frames_per_buffer? I can't search any tutorials on how to use pyaudio and now I am having trouble understanding the workings behind it. Thank you so much for the help!

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: You can have a look at the PyAudio documentation [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/).

Comment: I already look at it but I don't understand the documentation.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish ? According your question, you're not very familiar with audio development. What is your question ?

Comment: I am currently learning how to make a realtime audio classification